# "the Founder of Christianity would have been among her critics"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "the Founder of Christianity would have been among her critics" means that "Jesus Christ don't criticize her"?

> Mrs. Emma Hardinge—who became, by a second marriage, Mrs. Hardinge
>   Britten—threw her whole enthusiastic temperament into the young
>   movement and left a mark upon it which is still visible. She was an
>   ideal propagandist, for she combined every gift. She was a strong
>   medium, an orator, a writer, a well-balanced thinker and a hardy
>   traveller. Year after year she travelled the length and breadth of the
>   United States proclaiming the new doctrine amid much opposition, for
>   she was militant and anti-Christian in the views which she professed
>   to get straight from her spirit guides. As these views were, however,
>   that the morals of the Churches were far too lax and that a higher
>   standard was called for, it is not likely that **the Founder of
>   Christianity would have been among her critics**. These opinions of Mrs.
>   Hardinge Britten had more to do with the broadly Unitarian view of the
>   official Spiritualist bodies, which still exists, than any other
>   cause.

source: http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the Founder of Christianity would have been among her critics" means that Jesus would criticize her, if Jesus was alive today.

But the full sentence starts  "It is not likely that..."

So the full meaning is "It is not likely that Jesus would criticize her"  or "Jesus probably would approve her, if Jesus was alive today.

This is explained in the context.  She was "anti-christian" because she thought that they were "too lax".  Since Jesus was very strict, then he would approve of this.

"Christian" here means "Trinitarian" in contrast to "Unitarian". But you need to delve into the religious history of the USA to understand that context, which is beyond the scope of this answer.